# Returning two randomly chosen groups from a list in python

Tags: python, list, random

How would i write code that involves having a list of 9 people split as evenly as possible into 2 cars but they are placed into each car randomly in python?
Essentially i'm looking for a return similar to this:
    Car 1: Person8, Person2, Person4, Person7
    Car 2: Person5, Person1, Person3, Person6, Person9

Comment: generally people want to see you've tried something.

Answer (score 1):

Just shuffle the whole list, then just split that list into two chucks, one with 4 people and one with the remainder:

```
import random

people = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'eggs', 'ham', 'spam', 'eric', 'john', 'terry']
random.shuffle(people)
car1, car2 = people[:4], people[4:]
```

If you can't sort the list of people directly, use `random.sample()` instead:

```
people = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'eggs', 'ham', 'spam', 'eric', 'john', 'terry']
shuffled = random.sample(people, len(people))
car1, car2 = shuffled[:4], shuffled[4:]
```

Demo of the latter approach:

```
>>> import random
>>> people = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'eggs', 'ham', 'spam', 'eric', 'john', 'terry']
>>> shuffled = random.sample(people, len(people))
>>> shuffled[:4], shuffled[4:]
(['bar', 'baz', 'terry', 'ham'], ['spam', 'eric', 'foo', 'john', 'eggs'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import shuffle
x = [i for i in range(10)]
shuffle(x)
print x
mid = int(len(x)/2)
car1 = x[:mid]
car2 = x[mid:]
print car1
print car2
```